# Git использование в командной работе

Tags: git, gitlab

Подскажите пожалуйста в работе с Git

1. Первый разработчик создает ветку, работает в ней и пушит на гит
2. Второй разработчик тоже работает в ней, выполняет pull

Далее первый разработчик решает ветку закрыть и смержить в мастер, но что делать второму разработчику ? он же до сих пор в ней работает ? пушить ее же на гит как новую ветку ?

Comment: не получится у второго запушить

Comment: А что ему делать если не получается запушить ? он ведь еще в ней работает

Comment: А гит напишет, что нужно делать.

Comment: Чаще делать `git pull --rebase ...` с соответствующими параметрами.